# Поиск строк не содержащих подстроку в логическом режиме полнотекстового поиска

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу вернуть строки в которых нету слова 'b'.

```
SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE MATCH(`author`) AGAINST('param -b' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

Возвращает

```
Array ( [author] => param a )
Array ( [author] => param a )
Array ( [author] => param b )
Array ( [author] => param )
```

Используется таблица Myisam, на колонку навешан индекс `FULLTEXT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял из всяких док - 'b' слишком короткое для того чтобы быть словом, определяется настройкой [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)